# java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to Download image (.png) file from MYSQL.
some time it works fine.unable find exact problem.
it works properly on Jboss server. throws an error while trying to run in my local machine on Apche.

Please help me to FIX the error.
Here is my java code.

```
    try {
        conection = SQLUtil.createConnection(Constant.DataSourceName);
        st = conection.prepareStatement("SELECT image FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Userid="+ getUserId());
        result = st.executeQuery();
        result.next();

        if(!result.next()){
        input = result.getAsciiStream(1);
        }
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getSignatureImageDestinationPath());
        int ch = input.read();
        while (ch != -1) {
            output.write((char) ch);
            ch = input.read();
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
        result.close();
        SQLUtil.closeConnection(conection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e+":Error");
    } finally {
        if (st != null) {
            SQLUtil.closeConnection(conection);
        }
    }
```

Here is Stack trace output:

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:854)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getAsciiStream(ResultSetImpl.java:1275)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getAsciiStream(DelegatingResultSet.java:253)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getAsciiStream(DelegatingResultSet.java:253)
at com.ninenexus.model.Signature.getSignatureImage(Signature.java:173)
at com.ninenexus.servlets.SaveMySignature.mySignatureDisplay(SaveMySignature.java:69)
at com.ninenexus.servlets.SaveMySignature.doPost(SaveMySignature.java:35)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: where is your stacktrace?

Comment: What's the error, specifically, when it doesn't work? Be sure to close all resources in the `finally` block. Also, why are you using characters to represent binary data?

Comment: Marco Forberg.in cath block

Comment: BDKosher .i am closing all the opened connections..

Comment: Possibly not related to your problem, but your use of result.next is unusual. If your query returns more than one row then "input" will be left at whatever its initial value is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are calling `result.next()` twice. I'm assuming that your query returns only 1 row since you are trying to match by `Userid`. When the second `result.next()` is being called, there is no row to be returned in the `ResultSet`. This is why an `SQLException` is being thrown. Remove the 1st `result.next()` like so:

```
result = st.executeQuery();
if(!result.next()){
    input = result.getAsciiStream(1);
    }
```

Comment: That still won't work will it? It's saying if NOT result.next().

Comment: Doesn't matter, the call itself will trigger the exception.

Comment: OK, I can see that the exception will be throw by the second call. But lets say he removes the first call to `result.next()`. The remaining call will return true, meaning that the `input` variable will not be populated won't it?

Comment: Logically, I don't know what he's trying to do, but it won't enter the if block if the result set is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

The second `result.next` is moving you past the end of the result set.

I think you want

```
result = st.executeQuery();
if(result.next()){
   input = result.getAsciiStream(1);
}
```