# java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set error in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I tried to read the data from database and store the `ResultSet` in `ArrayList`. However, I receive the error `java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set` when I print the arraylist. I have checked that I don't have call my `result.next()` twice according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418258/java-sql-sqlexception-after-end-of-result-set-in-mysql) . Anyone have better way to store the result set? Then I can print it out at the location I want.

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rsVehicle=stmt.executeQuery("select * from vehicle");  
            while(rsVehicle.next()) {  
                vehicleList.add(rsVehicle);
            }
            System.out.println(vehicleList.size());

            for(int i=0;i<vehicleList.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(vehicleList.get(i).getInt(1)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(2)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(3)+"  "+
                        vehicleList.get(i).getString(4)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(5)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(6)+"  "+
                        vehicleList.get(i).getString(7)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(8)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(9)+"  "+
                        vehicleList.get(i).getString(10)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(11)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(12)+"  "+
                        vehicleList.get(i).getString(13)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(14)+"  "+vehicleList.get(i).getString(15));
            }

            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from job WHERE date = ?");
            ps.setString(1, date);
            ResultSet rsJob=ps.executeQuery();  
            while(rsJob.next()) {  
                jobList.add(rsJob);
            }
            System.out.println(jobList.size());

            for(int i=0;i<jobList.size();i++) {
                System.out.println(jobList.get(i).getInt(1)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(2)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(3)+"  "+
                        jobList.get(i).getString(4)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(5)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(6)+"  "+
                        jobList.get(i).getString(7)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(8)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(9)+"  "+
                        jobList.get(i).getString(10)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(11)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(12)+"  "+
                        jobList.get(i).getString(13)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(14)+"  "+jobList.get(i).getString(15));
            }
```

Comment: You are adding your complete ResultSet object to the list for each call to `next`, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I make a mistake. I thought I am storing each row of resultset in arrayList but my code is storing whole resultset in arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you add the result set to a list and then you iterate over that list to get the data, but the correct flow is:

- Extract data from the result set and put them in a list.
- After you can iterate the list to print the results.

The code should be something similar to:

```
// Create a new list of vehicles
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rsVehicle=stmt.executeQuery("select * from vehicle");  
while(rsVehicle.next()) {  
    // Create a new vehicle for each record returned from the query
    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

    // Set to the vehicle each property taken from that record
    vehicle.setBrand(rsVehicle.getString(1));
    ...

    // Add that vehicle to the list
    vehicleList.add(vehicle);
}

...

// Iterate the list and print each field you need
for (Vehicle vehicle: vehicleList) {
   // PRint each vehicle
   System.out.println("Vechicle brand: " + vehicle.getBrand());
}
```

Note: If you redefine the method `toString` of the class Vehicle you can call directly `System.out.println(vehicle);`